# How to implement select dropdown in angular 6 (Filter by search) , how do I filter object by its name property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am running angular6 app, I want to implement auto complete where data are object to be displayed in drop and it must be filtered as we type.

```
**template.html**
  <mat-form-field >
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
       <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value] ="option">
           {{option.name}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-autocomplete>
   </mat-form-field>
```

Typescript

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators'; 


export class Component1 implements OnInit {

 objectOptions = [
  { name:'Angular' },
  { name:'Angular Material' },
  { name:'React' },
  { name: 'vue' }
  ];
customerFilterControl = new FormControl();

 ngOnInit() {

  this.filteredOptions = this.customerFilterControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(value => this._filter(value))
  );

  }

_filter(value:string):string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.objectOptions.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)); // how do I filter values here
  }

  displayFn(subject) {
    return subject ? subject.name : undefined;  
  }
```

Note : I have imported following modules in app.module.ts
    MatSelectModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule

**It gives me error when I try to filter object by name property**

Comment: what is the error.

Comment: Move `objectOptions` inside the component otherwise your component doesn't "know" the property (as you try to access the property with `this` which means a component's property).

Comment: sorry it is indeed class property, I have edited my question even then problem exist

Comment: error :type '{ name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.                                at     return this.objectOptions.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you provided the error you are getting.

However, saying that I can see the mistake, it is this line:

`this.objectOptions.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))`

Here, `option` is an object, and you are trying to call `toLowerCase()`, I think what you were trying to do is:

`this.objectOptions.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))`

**Edit**
Just saw the other error you are getting.

`_filter(value:string):string[]`

You are declaring your function as returning an array of strings when you are actually returning an array of objects with a name property. If you remove the return type and allow typescript to infer it, you should no longer get an error. Or change it to:

`_filter(value:string): {name: string}[]`

Comment: Thanks noggin182 thats correct and the I achieved autocomplete through   return this.customers.map(x => x.name).filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));

Comment: No problem, changing it as you described will work but then you no longer the display function as your results are now the names themselves rather than the objects. If it helped can you accept the answer please?